# How to generate cocoapods xcconfig for new configuration?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

I'm using Cocoapods in my project and noticed in the Configuration section of Project there are xcconfig specified for different targets, in the format like:

```
Pods-{TargetName}.{configuration name}
```

Now I need to add another configuration, however I can only duplicate an existing configuration, which will have same xcconfigs for different target, but how do I generate new xcconfigs for all the targets in the new configuration, that is, the xcconfig that has .{configuration name} of the new configuration?

I tried `pod install` but it did not work.

Thanks!